# liquid trapped in wet sponge

Tags: estimation, capillary-action

If you soak a sponge in water, or some other liquid, and then let it hang then some liquid will flow down due to gravity but not all, some amount will remain trapped in the sponge by the capillary forces. Neglecting evaporation, and making realistic assumptions about the sponge material structure, dimensions etc - how to estimate the amount of liquid trapped in the sponge? What if evaporation effects are included?

Answer (score 0):

1)Take out the volume mass relation of liquid you are using i.e. volume occupied by 1 gm liquid 
2) weigh the sponge before soaking and after soaking with liquid
3)multiply the difference of sponge weight with volume mass relation of liquid.
         You should get the amount of liquid trapped in sponge.

Comment: This is an excellent experimental plan but what I had in mind was a theoretical estimate of the amount of trapped liquid.

Comment: The OP is asking about the amount of liquid held after some is allowed to drain out, not the maximum amount the sponge can hold.

Comment: So,You can weigh sponge after some liquid is drained out rather than weighing it immediately after soaking